# Firestore function saving entire document data to Algolia

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I have created a Function which is saving the **Entire Document** to `Algolia` when `onCreate` function is triggered. I want to save only three fields and not the entire document.

Here is my current function code:

```
exports.addToIndex = functions.firestore.document('questions/{questionsId}')
        .onCreate((snapshot: { data: () => any; id: any; desc:any; }) => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
          //  const descdata = snapshot.data().desc;
            const objectID = snapshot.id;
            console.log(objectID);
         //   console.log(descdata);
         console.log(data);
    
          //  return index.saveObject({ ...descdata, objectID });
          return index.saveObject({ ...data, objectID });
        });
```

I only want to save three objectid's:

1. **ObjectID**
2. **slatex**
3. **alatex**

At present, it is saving all 18 fields of the document. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you have modelled the data? Retrieving data from Firebase returns complete nodes so understanding how you have structured your data will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` may carry the entire firestore document.

For limited fields, I usually frame the index data separately; like below

```
exports.addToIndex = functions.firestore.document('questions/{questionsId}')
        .onCreate((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            const objectID = snapshot.id;
            let _index_data = {
                 'objectID': objectID,
                 'slatex': data.slatex,
                 'alatex': data. alatex
            }
    
            return index.saveObject(_index_data);
 });
```